# Different group id for dropwizard (io.dropwizard and com.yammer.dropwizard)

Tags: maven, dropwizard

Why dropwizard has two different groupId.
`io.dropwizard` and
`com.yammer.dropwizard`

when you will see in git pom file. it has `io.dropwizard` https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/pom.xml

But in its site, it is suggesting to use com.yammer.dropwizard.
http://www.dropwizard.io/getting-started/

I am confused. Please help.

Answer (score 9):

New version of dropwizard(from v0.7.0-SNAPSHOT) is under `io.dropwizard`

Previous versions(upto v0.6.2) were under `com.yammer.dropwizard`

release notes can be found [here](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/docs/source/about/release-notes.rst)

There is some important changes to be noted, if you have used 0.6.2 previously.

Renamed `Service` to `Application`.

Renamed `DatabaseConfiguration` to `DataSourceFactory`, and `ConfigurationStrategy` to `DatabaseConfiguration`.

Comment: In that case, I assume "getting-started" documentation is not updated and we should use latest code. (io.dropwizard). Am I right?

Comment: 0.7.0 is released I think. There are some notable changes in the new version. Please refer the relesse notes link I provided before you start.

Answer (score 0):

Manu is correct in that there are changes between 0.6.x and 0.7.0. 0.7.0 is not released yet, but there is a 0.7.0-rc2 candidate out.

If you want to look at the docs, you can use Sphinx to build the docs from source or just browse the docs directly on GitHub: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/tree/master/docs/source

Comment: Just as an update, Dropwizard docs for 0.7.0 are being published on GitHub pages and should be up on the main http://www.dropwizard.io/ site in a day or two.